# uncaught reference error function not defined

Tags: javascript, html

My print function button doesn't seem to work upon clicking. The print view page does not show.

Here is the html code:

```
<button class = "hidden-print" id = "print-click">Print New Orders</button>
```

Here is the js code:

```
function printNewOrders(){
  window.print();
  $("#print-click").click(printNewOrders);
}
```

Comment: put `$("#print-click").click(printNewOrders);` out of the function.

Comment: the button still does not work. :( @DIEGO CARRASCAL

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. As demonstrated by the fact that the answers given to you "don't work", we need more information about your setup before we can answer your question.

Comment: @PocholoDelenelaMendoza, is the button being created dynamically? if it does you need to change the event linker (sound great like that...) from `$("#print-click").click(printNewOrders);` to `$(document).on("click", "#print-click", printNewOrders);`

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/poch_MENDOZA/7uwm8sd0/ i've recreated the issue here. @DIEGO CARRASCAL

Comment: @PocholoDelenelaMendoza your html should look like: `<button id='print-click'>Print New Orders</button>` and your jQuery `function printNewOrders(){ window.print(); }' '$(document).ready(function(){ $(document).on("click", "#print-click", printNewOrders); });` don't forget to "id" your html elements to make the correspondence between jQuery and it.

Answer (score 1):

Your click event won't be bound unless you call the function `printNewOrders`. Even though if you call it the page will be printed without user's intervention. So change your code like below,

```
function printNewOrders(){
  window.print();
}

$("#print-click").click(printNewOrders);
```

### [DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/j8vfftpa/)

Comment: @PocholoDelenelaMendoza Check the demo attached with this answer. Did you include jquery in your page? Are you seeing any errors?

Comment: I did not include jquery. No errors as well when inspecting element. The function just does not work. Is there any more solutions?

Comment: @PocholoDelenelaMendoza `$("#print-click").click(printNewOrders);` This part will not work without jquery. If you want a non-jquery solution. you can use this https://jsfiddle.net/j8vfftpa/1/

Comment: The button still does not function. The print media view still does not come out upon clicking.

Comment: @PocholoDelenelaMendoza Is your site live? Or can you reproduce your issue in a fiddle?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/poch_MENDOZA/7uwm8sd0/ here it is bro. @Rajaprabhu Aravindasamay